# pass associative array value to $_get

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am trying to build a url query with an associative array like this:

`http://website.com/go.php?status=0&day=monday`

Here is the my code but it only returns the word array.

```
$status = $_GET["status"];

$day= $_GET["day"] = array(
    "monday" => "one",
    "tuesday" => "two",
);

echo $status . " " . $day;
```

Comment: Not sure quite what you're looking to do.  Can you explain further?

Comment: @Greg Bair i am trying to call a value from the array based on the url so if i change `&day=monday` to `&day=tuesday` its going to echo the word "two"

Comment: +1 on the comments above me, I'd be happy to help if you give us more information

Comment: @OhMrBigshot i am trying to call the values in the array based on the day variable. if that makes sense?

Comment: @OhMrBigshot it doesn't make sense. You don't call or pass any values in the code you posted. You're just assigning things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$_GET['day']` as the key to your array:

```
$days = array("monday" => "one", "tuesday" => "two");

// Test if your array $day contains a key
// equivalent to the value in $_GET
// (only if $_GET['day'] was passed in the first place)
if (isset($_GET['day'] && isset($days[$_GET['day']])) {
  echo $status . " " . $days[$_GET['day']];
}
else echo "No such day...";
```

Comment: thank you so much this is exactly what i was trying to accomplish